# Buying Patent that has been abandoned

Tags: abandoned-patent, buying

Are you able to reinstate a patent if it has been abandoned for 4 years due to failure to pay maintenance fees?

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a 24-month limit, assuming the owners could prove that the non-payment was "unintentional", but also "at any time after the six-month grace period if the delay is shown to the satisfaction of the Director to have been unavoidable."  35 USC § 41(c)(1), as effective in 2007.

Today, the statute reads, in part:

35 USC § 41(c)(1)

> The Director may accept the payment of any maintenance fee required by
>   subsection (b) after the 6-month grace period if the delay is shown to
>   the satisfaction of the Director to have been unintentional...   If the 
>   Director accepts payment of a maintenance fee after the 6-month grace 
>   period, the patent shall be considered as not having expired at the end of 
>   the grace period.